# Creatng a simple text menu: String out of bonds expection ( range 0 ) Java

Tags: java, loops, text, menu

I'm trying to create a menu that prints to the screen a set of numbers, through the numbersystem method. When I try to loop my menu, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at homework4_5.Driver.engageDriver(Driver.java:31)
    at homework4_5.Driver.engageDriver(Driver.java:47)
    at homework4_5.Driver.main(Driver.java:18)
```

I also believe that my method `NumberSystem` is not the issue. (As with using other input methods, I can get the method to produce proper results.)

I've run into this problem a lot with text menus. Can anyone help me? I think it may be that the scanner is receiving a blank string and can't parse a `int` from it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    public int baseCount = 0;
    public int numOfCols = 0;
    public boolean loop = true;


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Driver driver = new Driver();
        driver.engageDriver();          
    }


    public void engageDriver(){
        NumberSystem ns = new NumberSystem();
        System.out.println("Hello, please enter the numeric value corresponding to your counting/base system" );
        String temp = sc.nextLine();

        if(temp.charAt(0)== 'q'){
            System.out.println("Shutting Down the program...Thank You!");               
            loop = false;
            return;
        }
        baseCount = Integer.parseInt(temp);             

        System.out.println("Now enter how many columns you would like to display ( a value from 1 to 3 ) ");
        numOfCols=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The number table you requested is:\n ");

        ns.printNumberSystem(baseCount, numOfCols);
        if(loop){
           engageDriver();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a check before temp.charAt(0) like !temp.isEmpty()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the stacktrace its clear that `temp` is empty when `charAt` is invoked. Check that the `String` has content before attempting to invoke this method

```
if (!temp.isEmpty() && temp.charAt(0) == 'q') {
```

The main issue is that `Scanner#nextInt` does not consume newline characters. Therefore you will need to consume these characters to ensure that they are not passed back through the `InputStream` in the recursive call of `engageDriver`

```
numOfCols = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: I knew the error boiled down to sc.nextInt(). Thank you for explaining clearly what is occurring inside the scanner method! As a side note, to increase versatility in the menu ( add some other options that I wanted ) I ended up using nextLine paired with a charAt() statement, along with some helper methods to parse everything. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Use exceptions. If the user doesn't enter a string, then it will throw an exception. You can catch the exception.

```
try{
     if(temp.charAt(0)== 'q'){
            System.out.println("Shutting Down the program...Thank You!");

            loop = false;
            return;
     }
} catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
     //do whatever you want with it
     System.exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for some helpful try-catch information! As it stands I was more interested in what was causing scanner to fire a blank, rather than how to solve for this issue. Your solution would have been great if I had simply wanted to hot fix my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `nextInt()` it doesn't change line. So next invocation of `nextLine()` reads the remainings of the line. In your case it's `""` try to write something like `12 q` and your program will quit. 
To fix that you need to force change reading line by invoking `sc.nextLine()` after `sc.nextInt()`

Comment: Good explanation, helpful in understanding why Scanner isn't functioning! Thank you very much.